# Template class does not see inherited template member

Tags: c++, templates

Let me consider a template class which derived from a base template class. The base class contains a template member. In this case, usually members of the base class can be accessed from the derived class using the pointer `this`. It appears however that this is not the case, when a base member is itself a template function.

Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct base {
  T x;
  base() { x = 10; }
  template <unsigned int N>
  void increment() { x += N; }
};

template <class T>
struct deriv : public base<T> {
  using base<T>::base;

  void p()
  {
    using namespace std;
    cout << this->x << endl;
    base<int>::increment<1>();
    // The following statement causes the compile error:
    // expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
    // this->increment<1>();
    // Also the following statement gives error
    // base<T>::increment<1>();
    cout << this->x << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  base<int> A;
  cout << A.x << endl;
  A.increment<1>();
  cout << A.x << endl;

  deriv<int> B;
  B.p();

  return 0;
}
```

In the `main` routine the template member `increment` is called from a variable of type `base`. This works without any problem.
On the other hand, the member function `p()` of the `deriv` class tries to access to the template function `increment` inherited from base. Using the pointer `this` as in the commented line above

```
this->increment<1>();
```

gives the compile error

```
expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

After trying for a while, I found it possible, as in the code above, to access to the `increment` function via the scope operator

```
base<int>::increment<1>();
```

This however explicitly instantiate `base` with `T=int`. If I want to call the `increment` member from the inherited `base<T>`, with generic `T` class as

```
base<T>::increment<1>();
```

I get the same error as above.

I am using gcc 8.1.1

The question is: why using the pointer `this` cannot the compiler resolve the inherited member function `increment`? How can I get instantiate the inherited template function `increment`, from the inherited class `base`?

Edit: I added another case where it fails to compile, better specify the question.

Edit: small correction in the program, same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `this->increment<1>()` is invalid because `increment` is a dependent function template.  You need therefore need to use the `template` keyword:

```
this->template increment<1>();
```

Your `using` directive and `base<int>::increment<1>()` call are also not correct.  If `deriv` is intantiated with a type other than `int` neither of those will work.  You should use `T` instead of `int` in both of those.  When doing so the call to `base<T>::increment<1>()` will become invalid for the same reason `this->increment<1>()` is invalid.  You need the `template` keyword there as well:

```
base<T>::template increment<1>();
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed and corrected the wrong ```using``` statement right after I posted the question, but you were quicker!

Answer (score 3):

Unless you specify otherwise, the compiler assumes that the name you access is not a template, so both `<` and `>` are tokenized as less than and greater than signs respectively (the line is parsed as `((this->increment)<1)>()`). This happens because `this` and `base<T>` are both dependent on the template parameter `T` and the compiler cannot look up `increment` to see if it is a template. This holds for any case where the name on the left of an operator is dependent on any template parameter and the name on the right is template-id (name with `<>`). To solve this problem, you need to use the `template` keyword

```cpp
base<T>::template increment<1>();
this->template increment<1>();
```

Why does `base<int>::increment<1>();` compile then? Because it does not depend on `T` (refers to a known specialization), thus the name `increment` can be looked up to determine whether it is or is not a template.
But it won't compile if `T` is not `int`. gcc gives the following error
`[x86-64 gcc 8.1 #1] error: type 'base<int>' is not a base type for type 'deriv<long long int>'`
If `base<int>::increment` was public static, the code would always compile (not exactly because the compiler would compile about `x` not being static, but with additional changes it would).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, wasn't aware of this syntax.